# Increase test coverage for query IsSandbox =true

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, community

I am checking for sandbox with help of query
select Id from Organization where IsSandbox =true limit 1

but now in production and developer org my code coverage is going down to 33%  as this query is not getting satisfied.

How should i increase this code coverage?

Comment: Would you mind going in to more detail about what you're trying to do ? This may be the result of a design that should be improved rather than bypassing the consequences.

Comment: Code coverage drop to 33% on Production should be a warning sign that isSandbox is not used correctly, ie the code should be written to execute the same regardless the org. Check if the code can be refactored to minimize/eliminate isSandbox usage so you are still able to test all functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to 'simulate' being in a sandbox environment when running test classes in a developer or production environment.

The only thing I can come up to get coverage for that line is adding a check for being in test mode.
So instead of:

```
if (org.IsSandBox == true){
```

you can put:

```
if(org.IsSandBox == true || Test.isRunningTest()){
```

The question is, of course, if your test is then still functionally OK. That's up to you to assess..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm the class api version of your code from production and developer org?
Because ***IsSandbox*** this field is available after api version ***31.0 and later***. 
If its less then 31.0 then update your class api version and check it.

Refer [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) link.

Comment: My class api version is 32.0 so isSandbox field is available